Accessing nested typeclasses elegantly
I have a situation where one typeclass is "nested" in another one like this:
Class HasI T := {
  get_i: T -> nat
}.

Class HasHasI T := {
  S: Type;
  SHasI: HasI S;
  get_s: T -> S
}.

Now if I want to access the nested get_i given some HasHasI, the following does not work because the implicit HasI cannot be inferred:
Definition get_nested_i {T} `{HasHasI T}: T -> nat := fun t =>
   get_i (get_s t).

The following does work:
Definition get_nested_i {T} `{HasHasI T}: T -> nat := fun t =>
   @get_i S SHasI (get_s t).

Now I just wanted to know: is there a way to let Coq infer the HasI automatically so that my first definition (or something similar) will work again? Or is there some way to improve my representation of those nested typeclasses in general?

You need to allow the typeclass resolution mechanism to see an instance of HasHasI T as an instance of HasI T. See the following code:
Class HasI T := {
    get_i: T -> nat
  }.

Class HasHasI T := {
    S: Type;
    (* Notice the :: instead of : *)
    SHasI :: HasI S;
    get_s: T -> S
  }.

(* The use of this notation declares `SHasI` as an instance for HasI, as you can observe.
   Note that it would be strictly equivalent to writing explicitly:
   `Existing Instance SHasI.` 
   after your class definition
 *)
Print Instances HasI.

(* It works *)
Definition get_nested_i {T} `{HasHasI T}: T -> nat := fun t => get_i (get_s t).
(* And indeed did what you wrote explicitly *)
Set Printing Implicit.
Print get_nested_i.

